# Adding a url to a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, I want to be able to send confirmation messages via email or text message depending on user preference.  In those messages, there's a link for them to click to confirm.

For the emails, I put something like this in the view:

```
<%= link_to "Click here to confirm", confirmation_url(param stuff) %>
```

However, I'm not sure how to do the same thing for the text messages.  I'm using the twilio-ruby gem, and I only have a string I can send for the message.  Something like this doesn't work:

```
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new
client.messages.create({
  from: ENV['TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER'],
  to: phone_number,
  body: "Welcome to MySite.  Please click this link to confirm: #{ confirmation_url(param stuff) }
})
```

Basically I understand how link_to works to get the URL, but I'm not sure how to do it if I'm not in an html view context.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.confirmation_url(param stuff)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly!  Just had to figure out how to set the default_url_options per environment.